# Datagrid within Listbox within Window.Resources is always empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datacontext

I'm trying to use a DataGrid within a ListBox within a Windows.Resources, however, the Datagrid is always empty.

I'm using the MaterialDesign library for WPF to show the information in a popup (that's why I'm using the window's resources). I'm also manually setting the object's properties in the code behind just to be sure that there is data to be shown.

Here is the WPF code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate
        DataType="{x:Type time:TimeRecords}">
        <StackPanel
            Orientation="Vertical">
            ...
            <ListBox
            x:Name="LstList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Weeks}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel
                        Orientation="Vertical">
                            <DataGrid
                                ItemsSource="{Binding }"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                Margin="20, 20, 20, 10">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn
                                        Header="{Binding Sunday.Date}"
                                        Binding="{Binding Sunday.Hours}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn
                                        Header="{Binding Monday.Date}"
                                        Binding="{Binding Monday.Hours}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn
                                        Header="{Binding Tuesday.Date}"
                                        Binding="{Binding Tuesday.Hours}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn
                                        Header="{Binding Wednesday.Date}"
                                        Binding="{Binding Wednesday.Hours}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn
                                        Header="{Binding Thursday.Date}"
                                        Binding="{Binding Thursday.Hours}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn
                                        Header="{Binding Friday.Date}"
                                        Binding="{Binding Friday.Hours}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn
                                        Header="{Binding Saturday.Date}"
                                        Binding="{Binding Saturday.Hours}" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And the classes:

```
public class TimeEntry
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Hours { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Week
{
    public TimeEntry Sunday { get; set; }

    public TimeEntry Monday { get; set; }

    public TimeEntry Tuesday { get; set; }

    public TimeEntry Wednesday { get; set; }

    public TimeEntry Thursday { get; set; }

    public TimeEntry Friday { get; set; }

    public TimeEntry Saturday { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class TimeRecords
{
    public ObservableCollection<Week> Weeks { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Week>();
}
```

I have tried setting the Binding into the Datagrid's DataContext and even using RelativeSource but nothing seems to work.

Comment: why do you use DataGrid inside ListBox? there will be a DataGrid per item. use DataGrid only, remove ListBox

Comment: in other words: ItemsSource binding - `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">` - is incorrect, because it is expected to be IEnumerable, but instead binds to a single `Week` item.